# Improving this Scrapy crawler

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I've written a web crawler which extracts absolute links from the starting URL, and keeps visiting absolute links within the domain until it stops. Scrapy automatically doesn't follow duplicate links. The crawler works.

```
import scrapy

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test_spider'
    start_urls = ['http://homeguide.ph/']
    allowed_domains = ['homeguide.ph']

    # for the initial visit
    def parse(self, response):
        links = response.xpath('//a/@href').extract()
        for link in links:
            if link.find("#") == -1:
                yield scrapy.Request(link, callback=self.parse_link)

    # for subsequent visits
    def parse_link(self, response):
        self.logger.info("Visited %s", response.url)
        links = response.xpath('//a/@href').extract()
        for link in links:
            if link.find("#") == -1: # visit only absolute links
                yield scrapy.Request(link, callback=self.parse_link)
```

I feel like it can be improved, though. I'm not sure how. Is there a way to improve this crawler?

Answer (score 2):

1) You can use CrawlSpider object. It extract all links and follow it automatically. You can check it [here](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider)